# May I ask No Free Lunch theorem questions here that have been asked at math.se?

Tags: discussion

I have some questions related to No Free Lunch theorem, which is also discussed in machine learning. I am trying to understand the theorem in the setting of optimizing cost functions. I posted it on math.se [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107700/how-shall-i-understand-this-simple-example-of-no-free-lunch-theorem) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107088/understanding-no-free-lunch-theorem), but from my experience I have the feeling that few people there know about my questions. So I wonder if I can post them here to try some luck (not necessarily migrate but keep them at math.se, since some people just visit there and don't come here)? Or do you have some other suggestions?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross-posting is a very bad practice; you should just migrate those questions. This way Math will still have a trace of them leading to Stats, so you shouldn't miss the chance to get an answer from someone from the Math community.

Comment: Thanks! Which site is likely to have answers to my questions, in your opinion?

Comment: The abstract way in which you pose the question is more conducive to the math site.  The question itself is of greater interest here.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks! The first link is just asking about a simple example, which I think may be suitable for migrating to this site? The second link is about its formal statement, which I think may be suitable for staying at math.se?